# stats question: 3% tomatoes out of 100 go bad. prob 5 will go bad

Tags: statistics

In angels garden, there is 3% chance a tomatoe will go bad. Angel harvest 100 tomatoes and wants to know the prob that at most 5 will go bad.

---

was looking at it was that 3 will go bad so the prob must be 0. I think it is going to zero the more prob n will go bad. Its just $(.03)^5$. Right?? (No! wrong again)

Comment: No...that's the probability that $5$ out of $5$ go bad.  Here you need to use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you need to use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

You are doing $100$ experiments and you are interested in the probability, that exactly $95$ of them will be successful, where the probability of success is $97$%.

Therefore, your answer is:

$\mathbb{P}(X=95)=\binom{100}{95} (0.97)^{95} (1-0.97)^5$

If the question is that **at most** 5 will go bad, than you need the sum up the cases, where exactly $0,1,2,3,4,5$ go bad.

You can do that as Doug M suggested.

Answer (score 0):

At most 5.

That is exactly 5 + exactly 4 + exactly 3 + exactly 2 + only 1 + none.

$P(X\le 5) = \sum_\limits{i=0}^5 {100\choose i} 0.97^{100-i}0.03^i$

If we expect 3% to go bad, then "at most 4" would be greater than 50% and at most 5 will be greater than that.